# error: request for member 'empty' in 's', which is of non-class type 'const char' 65 | if (s.empty() || s[s.size() - 1] == '.')

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I am reading a C++ Book **C++ Primer 5th Edition** in chapter 4 there is a code block

```
for (const auto &s : text)
{
    cout << s << " " << typeid(s).name() << " ";
    if (s.empty() || s[s.size() - 1] == '.')
        cout << endl;
    else
        cout << " "; // otherwise just separate with a space
}
```

When i run this code and using text string it  is give me an error and the same when i use char*

```
`op.cpp:65:9: error: request for member 'empty' in 's', which is of non-class type 'const   char'
```

Comment: `s` is a `char`, it doesn't have any functions.

Comment: Looks like `text` should be `std::vector<std::string>` for this to work.

Comment: Thanks,  it works that way if i do , vector<string> text = {"H", "e", "l", "l",
         "o", ".". "W", "o", "r", "l", "d", "!"};